# Solspace Friends: Is there a way to show a list of all friends of certain member?

Tags: solspace-friends

When viewing a profile (member_id in segment_3), can I show all the friends of this person? I seem not to be able to find it in the docs.
Thanks a lot for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{exp:friends:mine}` tag is what you need and you can use `member_id` as a parameter. The [member_id parameter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends/mine/#member_id) allows you to pass in a segment variable among other means.

The Friends:Mine function itself allows you to display a list of their friends so you just need to output whatever information you need within this tag pair.

Comment: Thank you. Strange, I did read about friends:mine function, but as I understood it, this tag allows users to show their own friends = mine from their own perspective...... So I was looking for a tag called friends:theirs which does not exist. But now all is clear, thanks.